# C# Using Newtonsoft Json to change Property Name of Item in List based upon an Attribute

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I am trying to change the name of a property inside of a list by referencing a attribute on the list.

Below is code with an outer class A that holds a list of B.  If you notice, on "A" there is [DataMember, ItemName("C")].  In short, I want to use this "ItemName" attribute to rename the "Data" property in B, to "C"

Code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  public class B
  {
    [DataMember]
    public int Data { get; set; }
  }

  public class A
  {
    [DataMember, ItemName("C")]
    public List<B> List { get; set; }
  }

  public class ItemNameAttribute : Attribute
  {
    public string Name { get; }

    public ItemNameAttribute(string name)
    {
      Name = name;
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var a = new A();
      a.List = new List<B>()
      {
        new B() { Data = 1 }, new B() { Data = 2 }
      };

      var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
    }
  }
}
```

The Expected Json output that I want is

```
{
  "List": [
    {
      "C": 1
    },
    {
      "C": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

The current output I have is:

```
{
  "List": [
    {
      "Data": 1
    },
    {
      "Data": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonPropertyAttribute to change the names of properties.

This is the source code.

```
public class B
  {
    [JsonProperty("C")]
    public int Data { get; set; }
  }

  public class A
  { 
    [JsonProperty("List")]   
    public List<B> List { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: That is not what the question is asking.  I need to have the attribute on the list

Comment: <In short, I want to use this "ItemName" attribute to rename the "Data" property in B, to "C">. Use JsonProperty to change Data property in B to C.
I tested and get wanted result.

Comment: 1. I don't have the ability to add in the JsonProperty attribute. I can't change any attributes.  2. I already managed to solve the problem using  existing code + Dictionary.  It was complicated.. but i figured it out